# Increase the font size "by 2 pixels" or "to 2 pixels"?

Tags: adverbs, prepositions

Increase the font size **by** 2 pixels
or
Increase the font size **to** 2 pixels

Which one is correct?

Comment: It depends which you want to do. The second is unlikely because you would have to start with a 1 pixel font-size and end with a two-pixel font!

Answer (score 1):

If your font size is **10px** and you need to make it **12px**, say **"Increase the font size *by* 2 pixels"**.

If your font size is **smaller than 2px** and you need to make it **2px** (unlikely, but not impossible), say **"Increase the font size *to* 2 pixels"**.

Note that in both cases you need pixel**s** (plural), not pixel (singular).

Comment: And of course in the second case the font size is being *decreased*.

Comment: And any font that is only two pixels high is going to be completely unreadable anyway.

Comment: you'd be surprised at how much information the eye can glean from a character glyph that is only 4 pixels total.  It's shocking how readable it is!

Comment: @SimonB We don't know the context, but it's not always about readability to humans. There could in theory be niche cases where tiny fonts are applicable. In the olden days, black-hat SEO guys would stuff HTML pages with keywords for the sake of search engines, and then use tiny fonts for the keywords so human visitors wouldn't notice. There could be icon fonts that look OK even when tiny, etc.

Comment: It might be a shorthand for something, e.g. make small component 2 pixels wide. But if that was the case, the OP should tell us.